# How to move PuPHPet's html/index.html into annother dir

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

When using [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/#create) to build Vagrant configuration files, It creates a new folder on the project root `myproject/html/index.html`..

I prefer to move this file inside a subfolder so as not to "spoil" the root folder: so I put it inside `puphpet/html/index.html` **but** how to configure/tell Apache to load this file when the app is accessed using IP Address, instead of virtual host.

Now when I access the virtual machine with ssh and see the content of the folder `/var/www/html]` it is empty.

**Update**

After some research inside the created machin with `vagrant ssh`, I went to the apache configuration folder and found the folowing files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`: this is where apache keeps the config for the the websites. This directory has 3 files that configure the VirtualHost:

`10-default_vhost_443.conf  (for https)
10-default_vhost_80.conf

25-av_ztkymjg7l3qz.conf`

The first 2 are the default ones and the 3rd is pointing to my app's shared folder, and here's the content of `10-default_vhost_80.conf`

```
# ************************************
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/html

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
      Require all granted
      SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
    </FilesMatch>

  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So I think if can change the documentroot of this file to `/var/www/puphpet/html` then my problem is solved :) but how?

Answer (score 0):

PuPHPet defines the shared folder as

```
    synced_folder:
        blablabla:
            source: ./
            target: /var/www
```

so when it creates a new `html/index.html` inside your root project, it will be synced to your guest `/var/www/html/index.html`

If you want to move the html folder inside your puphpet directory, you can do

```
    synced_folder:
        blablabla:
            source: ./puphpet/
            target: /var/www
```

Comment: hmm.. This overrides my web folder :(

Comment: did you make other changes ? I did the same with `source: ./puphpet/`and I can see the same page than when it was under the root folder

Comment: No, I didn't do any other changes.. Please see my update on the question as I have done some inspections. Thanks!

Comment: changing your docroot to `/var/www/puphpet/html` or making the change on the shared folder with `./puphpet/` pointing to `/var/ww` is the same, both will result in your html files from the host under `puphpet/html/` to be accessible under the guest `/var/www/html/`

Comment: The problem is that I don't want puphpet to create the html folder in my project but still, want this folder to be mapped to the one I copied inside `puphpet/html/` as the `index.html` file there will appear when I type the IP address of the server withing the browser.. This `index.html` file is basically like a help or reminder that tells you to use vhost instead of IP address.